# Filtering & Paging API in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My requirement is to create an API that provides me filtered results page wise.

I have a JSONB structure with customer name and email id and want the API to filter based on these fields and provide paged results.

eg. /search/abc/pageNo/1   -> upon passing customer name the api should search all data with same customer name in DB and reply with 10 queries for display on page 1. if page value is 2 then it should provide with next 10 entries with customer name "abc"

Tasks here->

1. Fetch values of fields inside the JSONB structure in postgresql.
2. Filter based on the input value from api and fetch all rows which contains the same customer name or email id
3. Return a paged response of these filtered values.

**EDIT:**

Need help in creating a function that filters (not sorts) and returns a paged response.

I have also tried using @Query but it doesn't work->
I want it to be genric cause there are 6 columns and one column is JSONB type

```
    @Query("SELECT q FROM quote q WHERE q.column1 LIKE %?1%"  
           + " OR q.customerDetails->>firstName LIKE %?1%" 
          + " OR q.column2 LIKE %?1%") 
    public List<Customer> search(String keyword);
```

Comment: What is your question

Comment: @NicoVanBelle I need solution to creating this API that filters the data in postgres DB and provides with a page wise response. Code for achieving the same tasks mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

first, create a pageable object.
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, limit);

them just run
repoName.findByNameOfColumn(value,pageable);

you have to declare the function
findByNameOfColumn(value)
inside your jpa Repository

Comment: But in case of findByColumnName, i want it to be genric cause there are 6 columns and one column is JSONB type

//  @Query("SELECT q FROM quote q WHERE q.column1 LIKE %?1%"
//              + " OR q.customerDetails->>firstName LIKE %?1%"
//              + " OR q.column2 LIKE %?1%")

I tried using this query too but not working.